# Exception in thread “main” java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 at POSmain.main(POSmain.java:20)

Tags: java

I was wondering what is the problem here. i got a message saying this:
Exception in thread “main” java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 at POSmain.main(POSmain.java:20)

```
public class POSmain {
public static void main(String[]args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
    List<String> itemList = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<Double> priceList = new ArrayList<Double>();
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        String[] POS = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");
        String nums = POS[0];
        double value = Double.parseDouble(POS[1]);
        itemList.add(nums);
        priceList.add(value);
    }

    // Create a CashRegister object here
    CashRegister cashRegister = new CashRegister();
    for (int i = 0; i<itemList.size();i++) {
        cashRegister.readPrice(itemList.get(i), priceList.get(i));
    }

    // Create a ShoppingCart object here 
    Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(new File(args[1]));
    ShoppingCart shoppingCart = new ShoppingCart();
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()){
        shoppingCart.addItem(scanner1.nextLine());

    }

    cashRegister.readShoppingCart(shoppingCart);
    cashRegister.Receipt();

    // Create another ShoppingCart object here 
    Scanner scanner2 = new Scanner(new File(args[2]));
    ShoppingCart shoppingCart1 = new ShoppingCart();
    while (scanner2.hasNextLine()){
        shoppingCart1.addItem(scanner2.nextLine());

    }

    // Print the outcome of the cashRegister receipt and report
    cashRegister.Receipt();
    cashRegister.Report();
}
```

}

Comment: whats the input that you are passing?

Comment: cause i input in as in POSmain cart1.txt cart2.txt prices.txt

Comment: but it doesn't show any message or error with it